# show modal only after getting form submit response in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I am calling a pop up when click on submit button in Angular 8 but it is showing immediately before getting response, so I need to show the modal only after getting the response. Can anybody help me to do this, please?

Here is **.html**

```
   <div class="modal fade cust_modal save_qut_po" id="sav-popup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sav-qot-popup" aria-hidden="true">

      <input type="submit" class="upload-submit btn btn-primary" value="{{'Save Quotation' | translate}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sav-qot-popup"  [disabled]="!Form.form.valid" />
```

This is my **.ts** code.. want to show the pop up after getting **605 response**

```
quotationNo: any;
  onSubmit(quotationForm: NgForm, saveQuotation) {
    try {
      
        if (quotationForm.form.valid) {
        this.submitted = false;
        if (this.quotationType)
          this.motorQuotation.quotationType = this.quotationType;
        this.motorQuotation.addDriver = this.driverList;
        this.motorQuotation.premiumDetails = this.premiumDetail;

        //var formData = new FormData();
        //formData.append('motorQuotation', JSON.stringify(this.motorQuotation));


        var formData = this.getFormValue();
        this.ruleExecutionResult = this.executeRule();
        if (!this.ruleExecutionResult) {
          formData.append("actionName", "NEW");
          this.quotationCalculation();
        }
        else {
          formData.append("actionName", "APPROVAL");
        }
        if (formData) {
         // this.spinner.show();
          this.apiCall.getResponseByPostWithoutToken(this._commonService.quotationFormSubmit, formData).then(
            result => {
              if (result.data) {
                if (result.statusCode == 606) {
                  this.toastr.error("Error in commiting the data.");
                }
                if (result.statusCode == 605 && this.ruleExecutionResult) {
                  this.toastr.info("Quotation " + result.data.responseMessage + " send for underwriter approval.");
                  this.quotationUnderwriter = true;
                  this.quotationSuccess = false;
                  this.isShowPopup = false;


                }
                if (result.statusCode == 605 && !this.ruleExecutionResult) {
                  this.toastr.success("Quotation no is: " + result.data.responseMessage);
                  this.quotationNo = result.data.responseMessage;
                  this.quotationSuccess = true;
                  this.quotationUnderwriter = false;
                  this.sample = true;
                  this.ref.detectChanges();
                  this.isShowPopup = false;
                  // this.loginButton.getNativeElement().click();
                  
                }
              }
              this.spinner.hide();
            });
         
        }
      }
      else {
        this.spinner.hide();
        this.submitted = true;
      }
```

Comment: this might help you : https://github.com/IamFrost/angular-project-2-angular-crud-with-postgres-golang-api

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a service [ `ng g s service_name` ] , Lets put a variable there. Lets say it is called `savedResponse` [ don't give type ] . We will use it as **middleware** . ( and I would suggest you to use Angular http client - to take all advantages of fetch method )
2. I guess you are using 'X' component to call modal which is 'Y' component.
   so before calling modal :
3. use Angular Http client in service class
4. then write an `async` function in your 'X' component
5. then write `await` response.json (response is ur response) inside ur `async` function - it will wait for response
6. then save your response value in service class `savedResponse` variable
7. finally when u call modal, just take value from service class. (not from 'X' component or response)

[ I wish I could see your typescript code, so that I would be able to tell more. As far I understand - this has nothing to do with **HTML** . **HTML** only displays data, if you need a **slower execution** - do it from **typescript** - wait for response (use `await` method in `async` function) - then display it ]

Let me give you an example :

here is my **data.service.ts** . I receive data from API here

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private httpCLient: HttpClient) { }

  navigateFromDisplayFlag = 0;
  currentPurchase;

  setPurchase(purchase) {
    this.currentPurchase = purchase;
  }

  getPurchase()
  {
    return this.currentPurchase;
  }

  GetPurchases() {
    return fetch(('http://localhost:3000/purchases'));
  }

}
```

Here is my component class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-items-display',
  templateUrl: './items-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./items-display.component.css']
})
export class ItemsDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  purchases: any;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private router: Router) {
    this.GetPurchases();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  async GetPurchases() {
    const response = await this.dataService.GetPurchases();
    const dataService = await response.json();
    this.purchases = dataService;
  }

}
```

You can see:

1. I am using `async` method and inside it I am waiting for response using `await`
2. when response came to me , I saved it in a variable
3. Once you have saved your api response to some variable, you can use it anywhere you want.
4. Look in my code I only needed 2 classes, Perhaps you are using more classes , write a async method and save your Api response to a variable. then use data from new variable in your modal.

Comment: i have edited my question.. added Ts code.. pls have a look on it

Comment: but i cannot write async method bcz in form submit only i need to open the modal

Comment: you still can. before opening modal , get data in async , then send to modal